# Do all Safari 5 Extensions work on windows / mac?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I wold like to download some safari extensions, but I'm not sure if I should be looking for ones specifically written to run in Windows. Should I be looking for platform specific extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all Safari extensions run equally on Windows and Mac OS, so you do not need to look for platform-specific versions. All Safari extensions (that use the official extension API) are required to be written in pure Javascript, so they will work on all platforms.

Comment: I would like to add that although correct, some javascript extensions use other functionality that IS platform specific. For example an extension I came across which takes a screenshot, and only works on the mac.

Comment: @Nippysaurus That's pretty weird. Was it an extension that used the official extension API? I really don't know how you would do this using it.